# Where is the visual config view in AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda

I have been trying to look at the code that is deployed in an aws lambda.
There is an existing go function that is running in the go lambda.
However, I am not able to. AWS docs says we can look at the code through the visual config view, where is this view? This is the screen that I see, where is the view to see the code?
Please help.

Or is it because we are using a go server, only the executable which is a binary is running in the lambda and hence we are not able to see the code?
[image]

Comment: What kind of Lambda runtime are you using?

Comment: GoLang      is the language

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/code-editor.html

Comment: Scroll down to see the code editor.

Comment: I think go runtime does not support "code inline" but i'm not sure

Comment: @Adiii have checked that but there is no option to go to that mode

Comment: @AssaelAzran Or maybe since I am deploying a go server, only the executable gets deployed on the aws lamda

Comment: From my experience nodejs runtime works but .Net Core does not (uploading dll)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code inline is supported only for interpreted languages (js for example) and not compiled languages.

Answer (score 0):

Beside below lamda limitation, It seems console lamda editor does not support go.

However the documentation suggest to use code star.

> You can also **get started with AWS Lambda Go support through AWS
>   CodeStar**. AWS CodeStar lets you quickly launch development projects
>   that include a sample application, source control and release
>   automation. With this announcement, AWS CodeStar introduced new
>   project templates for Go running on AWS Lambda. Select one of the
>   CodeStar Go project templates to get started. CodeStar makes it easy
>   to begin editing your Go project code in AWS Cloud9, an online IDE,
>   with just a few clicks.

[announcing-go-support-for-aws-lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-go-support-for-aws-lambda/)

**Q: How do I create an AWS Lambda function using the Lambda console?**

> If you are using **Node.js or Python**, you can author the code for your
>   function using code editor in the AWS Lambda console which lets you
>   author and test your functions, and view the results of function
>   executions in a robust, IDE-like environment

[lambda-faqs](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/)

[image]

**Deployment package size**

```
50 MB (zipped, for direct upload)

250 MB (unzipped, including layers)

3 MB (console editor)
```

[lambda limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html)

[lambda-go-how-to-create-deployment-package](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-go-how-to-create-deployment-package.html)

Answer (score -1):

Based on the code size the AWS code editor will display the code. Since the size of the code/package is large AWS Code editor can't display the same.

But you can download the package from AWS Lambda function using export.

Kindly follow the below steps:

1. Go to the lambda
2. Select the lambda
3. Click on Actions
4. Select Export function
5. You will get few options. **Select Download deployment package.**

Comment: My code size, repository size = 1.4MB
after unzipping the deployment package from AWS I get a binary executable of 8MB
It is a go server, so I guess only the build is available in the lamda